# router-link to path with index

Tags: html, vue.js

I have 10 filters in table and I want that each name goes to specific link.
My table row

```
<md-table-row v-for="(row, index) in manage" :key="index">
```

I need something like this in first table cell:

```
<md-table-cell>
     <router-link to="filters/filter + (index+1)">
        <span class="center-content align-center">{{row.name}}</span>
     </router-link>
</md-table-cell>
```

So, "filters/filter1" goes to Filter 1;
"filters/filter2" goes to Filter 2...

But this is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<router-link :to="'filters/filter' + (index + 1)">
```

Without the colon (shorthand for `v-bind:`), that expression will be processed as plaintext.